# Classical EM wave: Wavelength dependence of modelling material as Lorentz oscillator vs Bragg diffraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, optical-materials

For convenience, consider a classical EM wave within a perfect crystal.

The Lorentz oscillator seems a good way to model material characteristics.

Yet in introductions to eg. X-Ray Crystallography, we read about Bragg diffraction through the crystal's periodicity, similar to a grating.

Is it entirely a matter of selecting the appropriate model for our objectives?

Or do materials begin to behave more 'grating-like' below certain wavelengths?

If so, does it relate at all with the plasma frequency of the material? Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the circumstance is. If,say, the size of the material sample is $\lambda/20$ then it is more like it being in a quasi-static field for all the atoms are excited simultaneously by nearly the same amount. If you have a sample $20\lambda$ size then the individual atoms will be excited by very different fields at the same time so their collective reaction will be very different. In a crystal where atoms are periodically placed and illuminated by a wave that is essentially coherent over the size of the sample you expect to see a coherent response from the atoms and this is what the Bragg reflection shows.

Comment: Lovely, thankyou. That is a very good insight regarding the sample size! Is there also a frequency relationship? For example, above a certain frequency the time parameters associated with the Lorentz Oscillator Model can no longer respond to the higher speed EM wave, and therefore the charges of each atom no longer have a pronounced dynamic response to the EM wave, and therefore begin to behave more like static teeth in a grating? Thanks